# How to select date among several similar date in a column in R

Tags: r, date, select, time, dplyr

I have a column like:
NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
[8] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
[15] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
[22] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
[29] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA
[36] NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31"
[43] "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31"
[50] "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31"
[57] "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2001-12-31" "2012-12-31"
[64] "2012-12-31" "2012-12-31" "2012-12-31" "2012-12-31" "2012-12-31" "2012-12-31" "2012-12-31"
[71] "2012-12-31" "2012-12-31" "2012-12-31" NA           NA           NA           NA
[78] NA           NA           NA

I want to save a data frame in R like:
Date
"1990-12-31"
"2001-12-31"
"2012-12-31"

is there anyone to help me.
I used the below code but it doesn't worked:

```
 total_flow_annuall$Max_date%>% select(which(sapply(.,is.Date)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a short Base R option that illustrates the solution with an example vector. The idea is to identify all unique elements that are not `NA`. No need to check for dates as there are no other types of values present apart from `NA`.

**Code**:

```
example <- c(NA, NA, "1990-12-31", "1990-12-31", NA, "1991-12-31")
date <- unique(example[!is.na(example)])
```

**Output**:

```
[1] "1990-12-31" "1991-12-31"
```

**Application**:

Given the code line you provided, the line

```
date <- unique(total_flow_annuall$Max_date[!is.na(total_flow_annuall$Max_date)])
```

should probably work for you.